# Inconsistent MySQL DATEDIFF behavior

Tags: mysql, datediff

When I use this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `my_table` WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), updated) > 2
```

MySQL executes the query with no errors and I get the count of rows that have not been updated within the last 2 days.  However, if I change the query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), updated) > 2
```

I get the following error:

```
#1305 - FUNCTION mydatabase.DATEDIFF does not exist
```

Any ideas why this is so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a similar problem where it would not work on SELECT if I had not set the LIMIT.

Try to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), updated) > 2 LIMIT 0, 10
```

It got corrected on a MySQL update. Try to update your MySQL version also.

Comment: Interestingly, phpMyAdmin was adding a LIMIT clause before executing the query, which fails.  If I add the LIMIT to the query myself, as you suggest, the query executes fine.  Must be a bug in phpMyAdmin version 2.6.4-pl3.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Verify that you don't have a space between `DATEDIFF` and the bracket `(`.

Possibly you could also try `SET sql_mode = "IGNORE_SPACE";`

Also check this [bugreport](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14124).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I definitely don't have a space when I enter the query using phpMyAdmin.  However, it may be that phpMyAdmin is modifying the query before it is executed.  As an experiment, I tried a newer version of phpMyAdmin (3.1.3.1) on my localhost, which executed the problem query just fine.  On my production server (which is hosted by a 3rd-party) the phpMyAdmin version is 2.6.4-pl3.  On my production server, phpMyAdmin is the only means I have of executing an ad-hoc query, since I don't have direct mysql shell access.

Comment: Well you can make certain phpMyAdmin isn't altering the query string and adding a space by setting sql_mode to `"IGNORE_SPACE"`. If this doesn't help as Frankie and the people in the bugreport have suggested, adding LIMIT apparently makes it parse correctly.