# datediff causing error in php

Tags: php, mysql, datediff

I have sql statement that works great in mysql, where I'm am using datediff. When I try to use it in php, I get an "mysql_fetch_arrary() expects parameter 1 to be a resource, boolean given in"

This the statement is...

```
$result = mysql_query("select hname, hsn, hmodel, hmake, htype, hwar, datediff(`hwar`, now()) from host where stype='physical';",$db);
```

I know the statement works in mysql

```
mysql> select hname, hsn, hmodel, hmake, htype, hwar, datediff(`hwar`, now()) from servers.host where stype='physical';
+--------------+---------+--------+-----------+-------+------------+-------------------------+
| hname        | hsn     | hmodel | hmake     | htype | hwar       | datediff(`hwar`, now()) |
+--------------+---------+--------+-----------+-------+------------+-------------------------+
| moscow       | XXXXXXX | Dell   | PowerEdge | R710  | 2013-09-13 |                     225 |
| sydney       | XXXXXXX | Dell   | PowerEdge | R710  | 2013-09-15 |                     227 |
```

When I remove `datediff(`hwar`, now())`, my page works.  I wanted to use that as field

```
$datediff=$row['datediff'];
```

Any clues as to why it doesn't work?

Comment: The `mysql`-extension is evil. Use `PDO_MySQL`, or `MySQLi` instead. See http://php.net/en/mysql-connect

Answer (score 0):

try to make limit in your query

```
   $result = mysql_query("select hname, hsn, hmodel, hmake, htype, hwar, datediff(`hwar`, now()) as dif from host where stype='physical' LIMIT 0,10 ;",$db);
```

look [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770851/inconsistent-mysql-datediff-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

Replace this piece of sql statement: datediff(`hwar`, now())

With: datediff(`hwar`, now()) as Diffdate

And recover it this way:
$datediff=$row['Diffdate'];

Bye XD

Answer (score 0):

You should give the selector an alias:

```
select hname, hsn, hmodel, hmake, htype, hwar, datediff(`hwar`, now()) AS diff from host where stype='physical';
```

Then you could access the column with the name 'diff'